# Azure Cognitive Search query results are not JSON but String in Unicode notation enclosed in double quotes

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

In the official documentation, the query result is shown in JSON notation with syntax highlighting as shown below.

[image]

In my environment, the query result of Azure Cognitive Search is not JSON, but a String with Unicode notation enclosed in double quotes.

How can I get the decoded string in JSON instead of unicode?[image]

```
"content\":\"\\n\\u30c6\\u30b9\\u30c8\\u7528\\u306e\\n\\nPDF\\u30d5\\u30a1\\u30a4\\u30eb\\u3067\\u3059\\u3002\\n\\n\\n\"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THis is a known issue with the portal search explorer, and will be fixed sometime this week. In the meantime, if you use any other HTTP client such as Postman to do your queries, you should the results in JSON format as expected.

Comment: Thank you very much.
However, there seems to be a problem that the unicode character string is displayed even if it is executed with the REST API.
The policy is to decode after acquisition with REST API.

Comment: This should be resolved now, can you double check ?

Comment: And I meant the actual issue, just in case. A fix was deployed.

Comment: Thank you. I have confirmed that it has been fixed.